# What counts as strong alcohol for potion refilling?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Strong alcohol is needed to refill potions, but the game doesn't really explain which items specifically count as strong alcohol. There are various alcoholic items in the game, and I'm not sure which exactly are used to refill potions.

Answer (score 19):

In the **Witcher 3** the base you can refill on seems to be: **Alcohest**

There is also:

- Dwarven Spirit

[image: Dwarven Spirit Icon]

- Temerian Rye
- Redanian Herbal
- Nilfgaardian Lemon

These were confirmed already.

You get it pretty early on in the game and it is pretty common. You can also buy it from **Brams Shop** in **White Orchard**

[image]

This is how it looks in the game:

[image]

If you are interested in some beverages that were used to brew potions in previous games and are considered hard liquor/strong alcohol in the Universe please check the list below.

### Top Quality Bases

- Alcohest
- Azoth
- Mandrake Cordial
- Wormwood spirit
- Wyvern Blood Spirit
- White Gull

### High Quality bases

- Cherry Spirit Cordial
- Dwarven spirit
- Plum Cordial
- Temerian spirit
- Zerrikanian spirit

### Standard bases

- Local pepper vodka
- Nilfgaardian Lemon
- Redanian Herbal
- Soldier's hooch
- Temerian Rye

Comment: Those look like the original potion bases from Witcher 1, as far as I can tell the concept of potion bases with different qualities doesn't exists anymore in the third game.

Comment: "in the Witcher Universe.".  "Although in the Witcher 3 the base you can refill on seems to be: Alcohest" why the downvote? I only added the list for knowledge sake. I don't see where my answer fails. @MadScientist

Comment: Your answer is contradictory, if those are counted as strong alcohol, you should be able to use them for refilling. But your second part says only Alcohest works. Either the list is superfluous or even misleading, or your second part is wrong.

Comment: @MadScientist I reviewed my answer and edited. To you agree now with the inclusion of the list? and with my phrasing for including it?

Comment: Alcohest is not the only one that works. Other items work, and they're all on the list from Witcher one, at least as far as I could experiment.

Answer (score 8):

According to various "tips & tricks" and guides found on the web, the general consensus seems to be that the item that is used for this is [Alcohest](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Alcohest). However, it appears that other alcoholic items will also work, if you're out of Alcohest.

When you meditate with Alcohest in your inventory, the meditation screen will notify you that your supplies have been replenished using that Alcohest. Once you run out of Alcohest, it will use other strong alcohol, like Dwarven Spirit or Pepper Vodka. See [this post](http://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/36lag2/guide_to_inventory_management_or_so_many_herbs_so/crf35vm) for reference as well. The game will default to Alcohest, and use the other items in order of sorting in your inventory.

I haven't actually tried this myself yet: but it seems that anything stronger than beer/wine would work, though an exact definition remains absent due to the many different items in the game.

Comment: Your first paragraph contradicts the second one, and the second one is correct. There are other strong alcohols except for alcohest.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, left-over from a previous edit.

Answer (score 6):

I just tried now which alcohol works by dropping whatever was used during meditation, drinking some potions again and meditating again. It is very likely I don't have all possible strong alcohols in my inventory right now, but these are the ones that could be used for refilling:

- Alcohest
- Dwarven Spirit
- Temerian rye
- Redanian herbal
- Nilfgaardian lemon

They were used in this order, Alcohest is the first choice, and if not available the next one on the list is used.