# How to refill my stock of Samum Bombs?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm sure I have the recipe for the Samum Bomb (to destroy monster nests). But after using two of my own crafted bombs, I see 0/2 in my inventory.

If I try to recreate such bombs with the matching ingredients, I get the hint: "You already have this item". That's not really true .-) Actually I have 0 of 2 of this bombs and can not destroy a third nest.

How can I replenish my stock of Samum Bombs?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You replenish bombs the same way you replenish your witcher potions - by meditating. You'll use 1 of your strong alcohols, but it will replenish everything.

A list of strong spirits can be found in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220205/what-counts-as-strong-alcohol-for-potion-refilling)

Comment: Usually an Alcohest, as these are most common in my experience.

Comment: @5pike Could you please specifiy, what do you mean with 'strong alcohol'? Is Beer (as example) 'strong' enough? How can I see, if it is strong enough?

Comment: @DavidYell - Yeah, I think it uses the least valuable strong alcohols first. I've tons of dwarven spirits, but it still uses the Alcohest.

Comment: Alcohest will be used first if you have in your inventory.

Answer (score 8):

If you meditate it will you use 1 alcohol and it will refill all your potions and bombs.

Comment: Could you please specifiy, what kind of alcohol I need (Beer? Some specificly named alcohol?)

Comment: You will only regenerate potions / bombs if you have a high-quality alcohol in your inventory.

These are listed on the Alchemy and Crafting tab of the inventory, and include items like "Alcohest", "Dwarven Spirit", and "Temerian Rye".